# routing error in application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got the following routes.rb

```
resources :api_users, :as => :users

get '/:controller(/:action(/:id))'
post "/:controller(/:action(/:id))"
get '/' => 'startsites#startsite'
```

I call the following action in application_controller.rb:

```
  def change_locale
     if Settings.language_supported?(params[:locale])
     session[:locale] = params[:locale]
     I18n.locale = params[:locale]
  end


  case params[:goto]
    when "user"
       if current_user.nil?
          redirect_to :action => :home
       else
         redirect_to :controller => :users
       end
     when "lecturer"
        if current_user.nil?
           redirect_to :action => :home
        else
          redirect_to :controller => :lecturers
        end
      else
      redirect_to :startsites => :startsite
    end
  end
```

and I got this error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/settings/change_locale"
```

how can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to define the `SettingsController`:

```
class SettingsController < ApplicationController
  def change_locale
    render text: 'it should be ok now'
  end
end
```

It can't be just a method in the `ApplicationController`.

Answer (score 1):

The first path "/settings" assumes that there is settings controller and second looks for settings controller action i.e. change_locale. You are defining change_locale in applicationcontroller and sending a get request to settings controller which is not defined. Therefore the error occur `No route matches [GET] "/settings/change_locale"`

This could be a solution

```
class SettingsController < ApplicationController
  def change_locale
    if Settings.language_supported?(params[:locale])
    session[:locale] = params[:locale]
    I18n.locale = params[:locale]
  end
end
```

And in route file

```
get '/settings/change_locale'
```